# PSEXEC command not working to execute a command with arguments

Tags: exe, batch-file, psexec

How do we execute a command with arguments in a different machine using the PSEXEC command. The below command is not working

start "" psexec \%serverIP% "c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Ldr64.exe" SETWOW -u administrator -p Helloworld /accepteula

Answer (score 0):

Just add another `\` next to the other `\`. The simple syntax for psexec in your example is:

```
psexec \\hostname /accepteula -w C:\WorkingDirectory executable.exe -u accountName -p PassWord
```